# How to combine multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to combine every 5 columns in together in the python dataframe so that 1-5 are combined, 6-10 are combined, etc.

df looks like

```
D1-7 D1-8 D1-9 D1-10 D1-11 D2-7 D2-8 D2-9 D2-10 D2-11
1    0    1    1     1     1    1    0    0     1
0    1    1    0     1     1    0    1    1     0
```

And want for example

```
D1-7-11 D2-7-12
10111   11001
01101   10110
```

Comment: Welcome, jordan. Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what do you want to do with the values? sum? concatenate? list?

Comment: the values concatenated

Answer (score 3):

Update:

```
df = df.astype(str) #Just make sure dtype object in dataframe
df.groupby([i // 5 for i in map(df.columns.get_loc, df.columns)], axis=1)\
  .apply(lambda x: pd.Series([''.join(i) for i in x.values]))
```

Output:

```
       0      1
0  10111  11001
1  01101  10110
```

---

Try:

```
df.astype(str).groupby([i // 5 for i in map(df.columns.get_loc, df.columns)], axis=1)\
  .sum().astype(int)
```

Output:

```
       0      1
0  10111  11001
1   1101  10110
```

Explanation:

Use `get_loc` method from pd.DataFrame.columns to get the index location of each column with `map`.

Then, use `\\`(floordiv) by 5 to group columns in groups of 5.

With `groupby` and parameter `axis=1`, we can `sum`, concatenate string values in each group.  Then, cast the results as integer, using `astype` to get rid of the decimal zero.

Comment: Is there a way to do this but ignore the first column so it remains not concatenated and start with column 2

Comment: Move the first column into the index then run the same command.

Comment: @ScottBoston Explain what your code do

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere as neat as above, but could try this:

```
for i in enumerate(np.array_split(df.columns.tolist(), np.ceil(len(df.columns)/5))):
        df['combo'+str(i[0])] = df[i[1]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype('unicode')), axis=1)
```

Splits the columns into chunks of 5, iterates through the list and joins them together with ','

Answer (score 0):

To do your task, proceed as follows:

Get the list of column names:

```
cc = df.columns
```

Create mapping for grouping. Target columns will be `C0`, `C1`, ...:

```
grp = { cc[i] : 'C' + str(i // 5) for i in range(len(cc)) }
```

Define the joining function (convert a Series of *int* to
a Series of *str* and concatenate them:

```
def myJoin(x):
    return ''.join(x.astype(str).values)
```

And finally, perform your join:

```
df.groupby(grp, axis=1).agg(lambda x: myJoin(x))
```

For demonstration purpose, I created the test DataFrame as:

```
   D1-7  D1-8  D1-9  D1-10  D1-11  D2-7  D2-8  D2-9  D2-10  D2-11
0     1     2     3      4      5     6     7     8      9      0
1     0     1     2      3      4     5     6     7      8      9
```

The result was:

```
      C0     C1
0  12345  67890
1  01234  56789
```